# application-settings not working as expected

Tags: nativescript

Wrote a small app and saved a string via application-settings module.

I can read the value fine within that same session.

If I close the app in the emulator and restart it in the emulator, I can read the value also.

But if I rebuild the project in the IDE (VS Code - pressing "refresh/reload" icon) - the app restarts and the stored value is no longer there.

Seriously?

Is application-settings stored data not persistent across sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rebuild your application, it will delete the old application on your smartphones + all the datas that was stored in application settings.

If you don't want that the stored datas disappear meanwhile you are changing the code you should use the livesync options.

In order to do that, go with a terminal at the root of your app projet and type the following command :

> tns livesync ios --watch

For IOS or

> tns livesync android --watch

For Android
I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks - very odd that it's done this way. Increases dev time for no good reason. I do use watch but sometimes it loses track.

Comment: I did a save of a 6K string and did a get - looks fine. Did a get after a restarting (not re-init) and there's an extra four spaces at the end. Works fine with short strings. Lovely!

Comment: Note: livesync is deprecated. Use run ios/android instead.